# Syntax error in copy assignment constructor

Tags: c++, visual-studio, constructor, syntax-error

I have been working on an own implementation of a Vector for unsigned ints to learn more about how defining own constuctors for example works. I'm also not using any of the standard library just to learn more about how to make a vector from scratch.

I have now written after som research some constructors that in my opinion should be correct but I'm getting some wierd errors that I can't seem to figure out why they appear. Might it be that I have misinterpreted how the constructor is supposed to look like?

All help you can give me would be mostly appriciated!

**Here's the constructor that I think is causing the error when it's defined:**

```
UIntVector& UIntVector::operator=(UIntVector&& other){
if (this != &other) {
    unsigned int * begin = allocate(sizeof(unsigned int)*other.vsize);
    unsigned int * end = (other.vAddress + (sizeof(unsigned int)*other.vsize));
    copyV(other.vAddress, end, begin);
    deleteV(other.vAddress, end);

    vAddress = begin;
    vsize = other.vsize;

    other.vAddress = nullptr;
    other.vsize = 0;
}
return *this;
}
```

**These are the errors I'm getting in visual studio (the constructor above is at line 48)**:

```
uintvector.cpp(48): error C2059: syntax error: 'if'

uintvector.cpp(48): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'

uintvector.cpp(48): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)

uintvector.cpp(60): error C2059: syntax error: 'return'

uintvector.cpp(61): error C2059: syntax error: '}'

uintvector.cpp(61): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '}'

uintvector.cpp(69): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'

uintvector.cpp(69): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

**The complete code of UintVector.hpp**

```
#include <iostream>

class UIntVector {
private:
    size_t vsize;
    unsigned int * vAddress;

    // Will allocate memory for the vector
    unsigned int * allocate(size_t size);
    // Will copy the range of the 
    void copyV(unsigned int * begin, unsigned int * end, unsigned int * dest);
    // Will delete reserved memory.
    void deleteV(unsigned int * begin, unsigned int * end);

    void reset(void);
    std::size_t size() const;
    unsigned int * getAddress();

public:

    // If UIntVector is called without parameter it should have 0 elements.
    UIntVector();

    // A constructor that just takes a single argument and then we create a vector with 7 containers.
    UIntVector(std::size_t length);

    // A copy constuctor.
    // Probably have to be explicit due to otherwise converting, don't know though
    UIntVector(const UIntVector& original);

    // Should be a deconstructor.
    ~UIntVector();

    // Should be a move constructor
    UIntVector(UIntVector&& other);

    // initializer_list
    UIntVector(std::initializer_list<int> list);

    // a copy-assignment, and a move-assignment, operator taking another UIntVector (potentially of a different size), and;
    UIntVector& operator=(UIntVector& other);

    /*
    – overloads of operator[] that makes it possible to access/modify elements at a desired index.
        ? The first element of the container shall be at index 0.
        ? An exception of type std::out_of_range shall be thrown if a user tries
            to access an index out-of-bounds
    */
    unsigned int& operator[](size_t index) const;
};
```

**The complete code of UIntVector.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "UIntVector.hpp" 

// If UIntVector is called without parameter it should have 0 elements.
UIntVector::UIntVector() {
    vAddress = allocate(0);
    vsize = 0;
    // should create just an empty vector
}

// A constructor that just takes a single argument and then we create a vector with 7 containers.
UIntVector :: UIntVector(std::size_t length) {
    // should take length and create a vector with 7 containers.
    vAddress = allocate(length);
    vsize = length;
}

// A copy constuctor.
// Probably have to be explicit due to otherwise converting, don't know though
UIntVector::UIntVector(const UIntVector& original) {
    std::size_t originalsize = original.size();
    vAddress = allocate(originalsize);
    vsize = originalsize;
    unsigned int a = originalsize*(sizeof(unsigned int));
    unsigned int * end = original.vAddress + a;
    copyV(original.vAddress, end, vAddress);
}
// Should be a deconstructor
UIntVector::~UIntVector() {
    deleteV(vAddress, vAddress + (sizeof(unsigned int)*vsize));
}

// Should be a move constructor
UIntVector::UIntVector(UIntVector&& other) {
    vAddress = other.getAddress();
    vsize = other.size();
    other.vsize = 0;
    other.vAddress = nullptr;
}

// Should be a constructor with initializer_list
UIntVector::UIntVector(std::initializer_list<int> list) {
    // std::initializer_list
}


// a copy-assignment, and a move-assignment, operator taking another UIntVector (potentially of a different size), and;
UIntVector& UIntVector::operator=(UIntVector& other){
    if (this != &other) {
        unsigned int * begin = allocate(sizeof(unsigned int)*other.vsize);
        unsigned int * end = (other.vAddress + (sizeof(unsigned int)*other.vsize));
        copyV(other.vAddress, end, begin);
        deleteV(other.vAddress, end);

        vAddress = begin;
        vsize = other.vsize;

        other.vAddress = nullptr;
        other.vsize = 0;
    }
    return *this;
}


/*
– overloads of operator[] that makes it possible to access/modify elements at a desired index.
? The first element of the container shall be at index 0.
? An exception of type std::out_of_range shall be thrown if a user tries
to access an index out-of-bounds
*/
unsigned int& UIntVector::operator[](size_t index) const {
    try {
        unsigned int * indexadress = vAddress + (sizeof(unsigned int)*index);
        return *indexadress;
    }
    catch (std::out_of_range& e) {
        std::cout << "Out of range: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
    catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << "Some other exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}


// Will allocate memory for the vector
unsigned int * UIntVector :: allocate(size_t size) {
    vsize = size;
    return (unsigned int *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned int) * size);
}

// Will copy the range of the 
void UIntVector :: copyV(unsigned int * begin, unsigned int * end, unsigned int * dest) {
    while (begin != end){
        *dest = *begin;
        begin += sizeof(unsigned int);
        dest += sizeof(unsigned int);
    }
}

void UIntVector :: deleteV(unsigned int * begin, unsigned int * end) {
    while (begin != end){
        free(begin);
        begin += sizeof(unsigned int);
    }
}

void UIntVector::reset(void) {

    unsigned int * address = getAddress();
    unsigned int a = {};
    for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
        *address = a;
        address += sizeof(unsigned int);
    }

}

std::size_t UIntVector :: size(void) const {
    return vsize;
}

unsigned int * UIntVector::getAddress(void){
    return vAddress;
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: the assignment operator is not a constructor. The object being assigned to already exists and is fully constructed.

Comment: Are those really all errors and warnings that you get? Sounds a bit like the result of an earlier syntax error.

Comment: Is that really the first error in the output? Which version of Visual Studio are you using? VS 2013 has no problem with that code, while VS 2010 complains due to its lack of C++11.

Comment: Oh alright molbdnilo I'm still quite new at c++ so must have remebered wrong from when I read about it and yes @Daniel Jour, those are the only errors I get. That there where som syntax error before that was also my guess but after going throught the code over and over I can't seem to find any syntax error and if I remove the whole "constructor" the errors disipear so my conclusion is that there is something wrong in the syntax for the "assignment operator". Can't figure out what though :(

Comment: Is your header named with .h or .hpp?  (the example lists it as .h but you're including .hpp, so just wondering)

Comment: @molbdnilo I'm using Mircosoft Visual Studio Community 2015

Comment: @Clairvoire it's with .hpp just a misstake from my side when I wrote this.

Comment: Why do you write `UIntVector&& other` instead of `UIntVector& other`? Is that a mistake or intentional?

Comment: @Dudeson I did some research around how a copy assignment constructor should look like and in those examples I found the most of the used && like I'm doing here in my code. So it's intentional but if it's correct I'm not 100% sure about.

Comment: @Dreamus: I never wrote any kind of operator using && instead of a regular & reference.

Comment: Alright, I edited the code so it's now with just one &, that still gives the exakt same error messages though, so the problem doesn't lie in that.

Comment: @Dreamus Either you want `&` or you want `&&`. Those don't mean the same thing. Simply swapping one for the other isn't really a good idea. If you don't know which one you want, you need to do some reading!

Comment: Yeah will do, but  still that doesn*t explain the errors I*m getting

Comment: With a parameter of type `T const &` the `operator=` is called copy assignment, with an rvalue reference `T&&` it's the so called move assignment.

Comment: Oh Alright, must have mixed them up, thanks for clearing that up. Do you have any idea why I'm getting these errors though?

Comment: It compiled on http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp11_online.php without errors. Maybe MS Visual Studio Community doesn't do C++11, or maybe you have to set an option to enable C++11.

Comment: That might be it, going to check that out when I get home

Comment: Works fine for me:                             1>c:\users\mvine\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\blah\blah\main.cpp(111): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was a matter of versions of visual studio, I downloaded visual studio 2013 instead of the latest one Mircosoft Visual Studio Community 2015.

I'm guessing it's due to the new standard and the this program was written for c++11 and therefore I got the error. Thanks a lot for the help you all provided testing it out.